# Vsync is disabling audio in android

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack, vsync

I am working on an app which uses Audiotrack to play the concerned audio.App allows the user to pause and play the audio at will .After pausing and playing 2 -3 times I cannot hear any audio while my log shows that audio is still playing.Before audio goes off I get `CPU Rendering VSync enable = true`

```
02-27 10:06:42.705 21811-21811/tuningforkexperiment I/System.out: Pausing...
02-27 10:06:44.715 21811-21811/tuningforkexperiment I/System.out: Playing...
02-27 10:06:53.435 21811-21811/tuningforkexperiment I/System.out: Pausing...
02-27 10:06:56.625 21811-21811/tuningforkexperiment I/System.out: Playing...
02-27 10:07:00.375 21811-21811/tuningforkexperiment I/System.out: Pausing...
02-27 10:07:00.375 21811-21811/tuningforkexperiment I/System.out: Playing...
02-27 10:07:00.385 21811-21811/tuningforkexperiment I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
02-27 10:07:04.055 21811-21811/tuningforkexperiment I/System.out: Pausing...
02-27 10:07:06.075 21811-21811/tuningforkexperiment I/System.out: Playing...
02-27 10:07:06.585 21811-21811/tuningforkexperiment I/System.out: Pausing...
02-27 10:07:06.585 21811-21811/tuningforkexperiment I/System.out: Playing...
02-27 10:07:06.595 21811-21811/tuningforkexperiment I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
02-27 10:07:13.105 21811-21811/tuningforkexperiment I/System.out: Pausing...
02-27 10:07:14.845 21811-21811/tuningforkexperiment I/System.out: Playing...
02-27 10:07:14.855 21811-21811/tuningforkexperiment I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
```

From what i understand after through this [link](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/implement-vsync.html) that VSync synchronizes certain events to the refresh cycle of the display. I am unable to understand why is it affecting the audio being played.Link or piece of code/advice is appreciated .
Thanks in advance.